# Regex to force upper limit of specific characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of words and I need to eliminate all words with zero or no more than one occurance of `i`, zero or no more than two occurances of `o` and zero or no more than three occurrences `u`.

For example:

`in` would work, but `inside` would not.

`on` and `octopus` would work but `commotion` would not

My best guess so far does not seem to be getting the job done:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"i?|o{0,2}|u{0,3}");
lines = text.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).ToArray(); // text is array containing the words
```

Comment: So, the words are tested as separate strings against the regex? As a list of strings?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just added the code where I call the regex

Comment: You say two `o`s should be omitted but commotion has 3 letters `o`.

Comment: Just edited the post again (thanks). Should read `zero or more than two`

Comment: Ok, I see the requirements have changed the third time after asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] text = new string[] { "in", "inside", "on", "octopus", "commotion" };

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(i.*){2}|(o.*){3}|(u.*){4}");
var lines = text.Where(x => !regex.IsMatch(x)).ToArray(); // text is array containing the words 
foreach (var s in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

**EDIT**

Just one warning. This solution would not scale to big number of letters due to backtracking. To improve scaling the backtracking has to be disabled:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?>.*?i){200}|(?>.*?o){300}|(?>.*?u){400}");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression only checks for subsequent characters, e.g. `uuu`. So this is not working. Using a regular expression in general is a bit difficult, since you would have to either run three independent regular expressions to check each character, or you would have to specify every possible combination of orders between those characters.

Instead, consider solving this without regular expressions. The following solution is very straight-forward and checks every string by iterating at most once through it:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "in", "inside", "on", "octopus", "commotion" };

var result = words.Where(x =>
{
    var maxCounts = new Dictionary<char, int>{ { 'i', 1 }, { 'o', 2 }, { 'u', 3 } };
    foreach (char c in x)
    {
        if (maxCounts.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            maxCounts[c]--;
            if (maxCounts[c] < 0)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Could just use a simple regex with 3 `|` alternations.

For matching if input is a single word.

```
i.*?i|o(?:.*?o){2}|u(?:.*?u){3}
```

Or for matching words out of a text.

```
\b(?:(?>\w*?i){2}|(?>\w*?o){3}|(?>\w*?u){4})\w*
```

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(?:` opens a non capture [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `(?>` opens an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)
- `\w` matches a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

[See demo at regexhero](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3A(%3F%3E%5Cw*%3Fi)%7B2%7D%7C(%3F%3E%5Cw*%3Fo)%7B3%7D%7C(%3F%3E%5Cw*%3Fu)%7B4%7D)%5Cw*&i=in%20inside%20on%20octopus%20commotion%20commision%20undergrounduturn%0D%0A%0D%0Ai%20ii%20iii%20o%20oo%20ooo%20oooo%20u%20uu%20uuu%20uuuu%20uuuuu%0D%0A%0D%0Aaeiouaei)